# How can I return specific lines in python 2.7 by using f.readline()

Tags: python, text-files, readlines

I am writing a program that needs to read only a specific line of a text file, say line 3, but I can't figure out a way to do that. I've tried

```
    target = open(filename)
    lines = target.readlines()
    print lines[3]
```

but that for some reason does not work. If anyone can help me that would be great.

Comment: "that for some reason does not work"  -- Can you be more specific?  Do you get an index error?  Is the data wrong?  How do you know it's wrong? etc.  As it is, we're really just guessing at the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python uses 0-based indexing. This means that the first line in your file is at `lines[0]` and the second line in your file is at `lines[1]` and so on.
As a result, the third line (the one that you want) is at `lines[2]` and not at `lines[3]`

For example:

```
In [78]: lines
Out[78]: ['line1', 'line2', 'line3', 'line4']

In [79]: lines[0]
Out[79]: 'line1'

In [80]: lines[1]
Out[80]: 'line2'

In [81]: lines[2]
Out[81]: 'line3'
```

If you want to accumulate only specific lines in your file:

```
def readSpecificLines(filepath, lines):
    # lines is a list of line numbers that you are interested in. Feel free to start with line number 1
    lines.sort()
    i=0
    answer = []
    with open(filepath) as infile:
        fileReader = enumerate(infile, 1)
        while i<len(lines):
            nextLine = lines[i]
            lineNum, line = next(fileReader)
            if lineNum == nextLine:
                answer.append(line)
                i += 1
    return answer
```

Comment: yes thank you for explaining that to me, for i did not know, but what arguments would i give f.readline() for me to read specific lines? thanks again.

Comment: @Hanson: without knowing the contents of the file, that would be very difficult. I've posted a slight workaround for your case, though